# More integration of Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange-2.0, integration

Hi,

This is going to come out as a bit of a rant so forgive me, however, I do sincerely like StackOverflow, I think it filled a very important void on the net. I also think the whole concept of StackExchange is a great idea and I do really want it to succeed. It's a great Q&A engine we have here, and it would be great if we could extend it beyond just programming.

However, I do think that there are some things that could be improved. The main issue I have is there should be much tighter integration behind the sites. It's getting to a point where there are so many sites now and each supposedly with their own definition of what is on or off topic that you get to a point where if you have to find or ask a question, you have to carefully select which site is most appropriate. I think it should be helping you decide. So you should be able to go to a generic SE page to find or ask a question, and it should than try to direct you to the site that is most appropriate.

I really like the Inbox feature - but I think there should be a SE wide control panel page. And I don't understand why you have to register with every single SE site. To me, it doesn't make much sense - I know it's only a few more clicks, but you should be able to register with one, and it should be register you with all the sites.

I understand the whole concept of different points with different SE sites - that's cool, they can still implement that, but I feel like SE would be so much better if moving from one site to another was more seamless. I feel like one of the main aims of StackOverflow initially was to have a site where you didn't get lost in an endless categorisation of topics and I feel all these SE sites popping up and not being integrated together is achieving just that.

Comment: +1 for the idea of offering site suggestions.  "It looks like you might be asking about Underwater Basketmaking; click here for  wetweavers.stackexchange.com?"

Answer (score 1):

I like the categorization, since I don't want cooking questions mixed with programming questions. Sure you have similar sites (stackoverflow and programmers, ubuntu and unix) but most of the other sites are very clearly defined and unrelated to the rest.

The categorization isn't even extreme. You have a site for your general topic (Eg Ubuntu) and tags for your specific topic (CLI, Ubuntu Server, etc). This is just to keep things separate so that you can focus on answering questions you know. If you poll them all together, then you just get a mess of questions with their own tagging systems. `[CLI]` could mean Ubuntu commands, writing a bash GUI, or best way to parse arguments.

And if you do for some reason want to know all the questions, https://stackexchange.com/ actually does that already by displaying whats on top. Unfortunately its not sortable, but thats a minor problem. If you can tell me a use for that page, then I'll make it a normal problem instead.

---

As for a global registration, I do agree with you there. The only people who would actually want this are people that for some reason want to isolate an account from the rest of their profile. It's a weird process that you register an account just to have it automatically associated and synced with the rest of your accounts.

Comment: I'm not saying we should merge all the SE sites into one. I'm just saying that there should be more integration between sites, more tools for you to manage your activities on all of the sites at once, instead of having to deal with one at a time.

Comment: @Roboshop Thats a side effect of separation though: Each site is a separate entity. I consider the stackexchange menu enough integration for me.